# express - config file gets called called before app or server files which returns env variable to be undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, es6-modules, dotenv

in my app the `server.ts` is the entrypoint which serves the app in port. all app.use is done in the `app.ts` file where the `dotenv` is called. As far as I know you are only supposed to call `dotenv` once and the entire app should have the variables. But for some reason the config file gets loaded first before the app or server files which is when the env variable `process.env.WHITELIST_ORIGINS` starts with undefined. I cannot understand the reason why this is happening. Is there any way to fix this without having to call `dotenv` again from the config file

server.ts

```
import http from 'http'
import { Socket } from 'socket.io'
import app from './app'
import { setIO } from './config'

const server = http.createServer(app)

const io = setIO(server)

io.on('connection', function (socket: Socket) {
  console.log('New client connected with id => ', socket.id)

  socket.on('disconnect', function (reason): void {
    console.log('A client disconnected with id => ', socket.id, ' reason => ', reason)
  })
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 8095

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running`)

})

console.log('server call')
```

app.ts

```
import compression from 'compression'
import cors from 'cors'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import express, { Application } from 'express'
import helmet from 'helmet'
import { errorHandler, verifyToken } from './middleware'
import router from './router'

dotenv.config()

const app: Application = express()

app.use(compression())
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(helmet())
app.use(verifyToken)
app.use('/', router)
app.use(errorHandler)

console.log('app call')

export default app
```

config/socket-config.ts

```
import { Server as HttpServer } from 'http'
import { Server } from 'socket.io'
// import dotenv from 'dotenv'
// dotenv.config() - If this is called here it works fine.

let _io: Server

const whitelistOrigins = process.env.WHITELIST_ORIGINS
console.log("whitelistOrigins", whitelistOrigins) // This logs undefined

console.log('whitelistOrigins', whitelistOrigins)

export const setIO = (server: HttpServer): Server => {
  _io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: whitelistOrigins,
      methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
      credentials: true,
    },
    allowEIO3: true,
  })
  return _io
}

export const getIO = () => {
  return _io
}

console.log('socket call')
```

Here is the order of how console logs

```
whitelistOrigins undefined
socket call
app call
server call
App running
```

Comment: Where does `socket-config.ts` come into play?

Comment: in `server.ts` there is a line `const io = setIO(server)`. i'm using barrel export

Comment: That's not what I asked. All you have is `import ... from './config'` but where is `import ... from './path/to/socket-config'`?

Comment: inside the config folder there is an `index.ts` file. which has this line of code `export * from './socket-config'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is described in detail within the [dotenv docs](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#how-do-i-use-dotenv-with-import)

> When you run a module containing an `import` declaration, the modules it imports are loaded first, then each module body is executed in a depth-first traversal of the dependency graph, avoiding cycles by skipping anything already executed.

For this reason, dotenv provides a specific import that executes `config()` within its body.

```js
import 'dotenv/config';
```

It's best to add this as close to your app's entry-point as possible. I would place this first in `server.ts`

Comment: yes. just added `import 'dotenv/config'` in app.tx and removed the rest of dotenv related stuff and it works fine now. thanks for the answer

Comment: @paperskyline I would definitely place it in `server.ts` otherwise you run the risk of further load-ordering issues